# How to find the reason for intermittent failing unit test containing await/async code?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, async-await

I'm using [xUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) for my unit tests in a Windows Store application built with WinRT C#. The code under test has calls to awaited async methods and the problem is that some of the sometime fail and sometime succeed. My guess is that some continuations of awaited code are executed on a different synchronization context than the captured ones and then there is some `Task` somewhere in the call chain that isn't awaited. However I can't find any such place.
How can I find the reason for the bug?

Comment: We have no idea what you're awaiting, or what your code does. That makes it *really* hard to help you...

Comment: in addition to Jon's comment, are there any patterns to when it succeeds and fails?  Does it always succeed if you run the tests from VS, but fail during a CI build?  Does it sometimes succeed and sometimes fail in the same environment, indicating a thread/race/timing situation?

Comment: @JonSkeet: the question was _how_ I can find the reason for the bug and not the bug itself, i.e. what tools and/or techniques there are available. The above and the fact that there's quite a lot of code involved were the reasons I omitted the code but I shall try to isolate a reproducible sample for you.

Comment: @JamesManning: I've only tested on my machine and sometimes it succeeds and sometime it fails and I haven't really see any pattern.

Comment: @Christian: It's incredibly difficult to give advice with so little go on, not knowing *anything* about what your tests like or even what your failures are.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your unit tests are `async Task` instead of `async void`. `async void` unit tests are [not yet supported by xUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9752).

If you have an exception in an `async void` unit test, [there is a race condition where it may erroneously succeed](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html) (link to my blog post that goes into more details; it discusses MSTest but the same situation exists for xUnit).

Comment: Not using async void in the tests. Thanks for the links though.

Comment: Are you using `async void` *at all*? If you ignore (never `await`) an `async Task`, then it won't fail even if it causes an exception (the exception is silently swallowed). OTOH, `async void` will raise its exceptions directly on its `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: no not using async void anywhere except in UI event handlers and I haven't found any place where a Task isn't awaited.